# Laravel + Vuejs. En mi servidor recibo un error 404 al hacer un axios post donde 'en mi local funciona' correctamente

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

tengo un componente para crear personsas:

El axios al que llama este este:

```
axios.post(this.$props.route_persona_create, formData, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data === true) {
                        that.toast('Guardado correctamente !','success');
                    }
                    else{
                        that.toast('Error al guardar!','error');
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    that.toast('Error critico! = '+error,'error');
                });
```

El componente lo llamo desde mi vista `persona/create` de la siguiente manera:

```
<persona-create :route_persona_create="'{{route('persona.store')}}'"   :generos_param="{{$generos->toJson()}}" :personas_param="{{$personas->toJson()}}"></persona-create>
```

*En mi local funciona* pero al hacer el deploy me devuelve un 404... Creo que es por tema de rutas relativas o algo, por eso estoy probando ahora con el helper `route()` ...

La ruta es de tipo `resource`.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con definir la url base de axios

```
    import axios from 'axios';

    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/' // the url of our server
    })

    export const DoPost = async (url, data = {}, config = {}) => {
        const response = await axiosInstance.post(url, data, config);
        return await response.data;
    };
```